# Airbag Deployment

Tags: calculus

Was reading about airbag deployment but couldn't really get a concrete answer to the following.

What kind of calculus is involved in the deployment of an airbag in a car and where exactly?

Comment: Partial differential equations!?

Comment: Quite a lot.  The basic question is, given a deceleration fast enough (to trigger the airbags - 1st DE), how fast must the airbags fill (2nd DE) so that they are full enough to reduce the deceleration of a human by a fixed amount or less (3rd DE).  In practice, these are 'linked" DEs, so you could argue one system of 3 DES (or even 1 DE).